# Is it possible to have one thread per gdb instance?

Tags: multithreading, gdb, terminal-emulator

Now I know that gdb enables us to switch between threads executing.

But, but, for greater convenience, I'd like to know if it's possible to have as many terminal emulators open as threads in the application, and have a gdb instance in each of these emulators, each bound to a particular thread?

Answer (score 0):

> and have a gdb instance in each of these emulators, each bound to a
>   particular thread

You can't attach multiple gdb instances to the same process. This is a limitation of `ptrace` syscall used by gdb. From [man ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

```
   EPERM  The specified process cannot be traced.  This could be because
          the tracer has insufficient privileges (the required
          capability is CAP_SYS_PTRACE); unprivileged processes cannot
          trace processes that they cannot send signals to or those
          running set-user-ID/set-group-ID programs, for obvious
          reasons.  Alternatively, the process may already be being
          traced, or (on kernels before 2.6.26) be init(1) (PID 1).
```